# suppressDragLeaveHidesColumns property from AG-grid Vue not working

Tags: vue.js, ag-grid-vue

I am using AG-Grid 26.2 version and Vue 2.

What I am trying to do is that when a user drags a column outside the grid, the column should not disappear.

But the property is not working.

```
<ag-grid-vue :suppressDragLeaveHidesColumns="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how it works with the Vue framework but the mistake I did while using the `suppressDragLeaveHidesColumns` option was the I was adding it in the `columnDefs` instead of the gridOptions...

So, the correct way for using it with the vanilla javascript is

```
const gridOptions = {
  columnDefs: columnDefs,
  defaultColDef: {
    width: 150,
  },
  suppressDragLeaveHidesColumns: true,
};
```

Other than that I guess you could try using the `ag-grid-vue` tag like the following:

`<ag-grid-vue :suppressDragLeaveHidesColumns="true"></ag-grid-vue>`

That's what I saw in their official example here: https://www.ag-grid.com/vue-data-grid/column-moving/#simple-example

Comment: I tried using the option in the gridOptions as well, but it didn't work. I found that we had AG-Grid being added as a script in the HTML instead of being added via a package manger and that is why several options didn't work like tooltipDelay, suppressDragLeaveHidesColumns etc.